# Don't use npm Orientjs in Nativescript

Tags: npm, nativescript

I'm using nativescript to build android application and using database is Orientdb at homepage http://orientdb.com/ . I'm trying to connect orientdb in Nativescript, use npm Orientjs at homepage https://www.npmjs.com/package/orientjs but have error. The following is the installation process:
step 1: i use command `npm install orientjs --save`
here is code in package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.KerryExpressDelivery",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "1.7.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "orientjs": "^2.1.11",
    "tns-core-modules": "1.7.1"
  }
}
```

step 2: i use command `var orientDb = require("orientjs");` in file.js but when build app in emulator, get error

```
com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "net", relative to: /app/tns_modules/
    at com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:220)
    at com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60)
    at com.tns.Platform.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Platform.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Platform.java:816)
    at com.tns.Platform.callJSMethod(Platform.java:715)
    at com.tns.Platform.callJSMethod(Platform.java:694)
    at com.tns.Platform.callJSMethod(Platform.java:684)
    at com.tns.gen.android.view.View_OnClickListener_ftns_modules_ui_button_button_l19_c42__.onClick(android.view.View$OnClickListener.java)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because OrientDB uses some other node modules that do not work in NativeScript. Although {N} is JS based not all npm modules will work out of the box. NPM Modules that depend browser or node objects will not work.